# Apache mod_rewrite subdomain and URL arguments

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, mod-rewrite

I am trying to write an Apache mod_rewrite that can take in information from the subdomain, and after the domain and pass it as a couple of variables to a PHP script.

Here is what I have so far, with this I can either get the subdomain, or the URL arguments.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^./]+)\.domain\.com/([a-zA-Z0-9/-]+)$
RewriteCond %1 !=www
RewriteRule ^ redirect.php?subdomain=%1&args=$2

RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9/-]+)$ redirect.php?args=$1 [L]
```

mod_rewrite is enabled, and we are using a wildcard A-record to point all traffic to this server *.domain.com

Additionally, I do apologize if this is posted elsewhere, I have been trying to solve this off and on for the last month and have not figured it out, or found the answer posted anywhere.

Comment: Can you clarify the behavior that you're seeing, and what you expect to see?  Looks like your first `RewriteCond` will never get a match, so I'm guessing just your second `RewriteRule` is working?

Answer (score 0):

As Shane Madden already mentioned, the first `RewriteCond` doesn't look like it will match anything.  The reason is twofold: firstly that the first `.` is not escaped and secondly that the %{HTTP_HOST} variable does not contain any slashes so the whole section after `domain\.com` will not match anything.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^./]+)\.domain\.com/([a-zA-Z0-9/-]+)$
```

I've never used %1 on the left side of a RewriteCond before.  Unless you're sure that this works, if you have more problems try removing this line to eliminate it as a possible cause.  There also shouldn't be an `=` sign in there.  Simply `!www` is what you want here.  If you do have problems with this line, change it to use the `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable instead of %1.

```
RewriteCond %1 !=www
```

The `$2` in the substitution of this RewriteRule has no matching set of brackets in the pattern, hence it will be empty.  You will probably want to add a larger pattern to this one.  If it only has one matching set of brackets, $1 will be what you want, even if you already have %1 in the substitution.  I suspect you will also want to make this `/redirect.php...` if you're doing this in the configuration files and not in a .htaccess.

```
RewriteRule ^ redirect.php?subdomain=%1&args=$2
```

Also, I might add that matching simply `^` is prone to creating loops.  Be careful with that one.